# How should I change this scraping PHP script to work with this table?

Tags: php, web-scraping

I'm using this code to scrape some info from a table on a website. One example I have works, because it has a row of `th`, followed by `tr`, `td` (the `th` is the first row above the other rows horizontally).

```
$dom = new \simple_html_dom($html);
        $rows = $dom->find('table.table-bordered tbody tr');
        $header = [];
        foreach ($rows as $row) {
            if(!empty($header)) break;
            foreach ($row->find('th') as $key=>$th) {
                $header[] = trim(html_entity_decode($th->plaintext));
            }
        }
        $cells = [];
        foreach ($rows as $row) {
            $cell = [];
            foreach ($row->find('td') as $key=>$td) {
                $cell[$header[$key]] = trim(html_entity_decode($td->plaintext));
            }
            if(!empty($cell)) {
                $cells[] = $cell;
            }
        }
```

The problem is that another example table I have has a different structure and I'm unsure how to change the code to reflect it. The `th` is on each row vertically as the first column of the table. Thus the first `th` gets repeated in the output as the key for all rows.

```
<table class="table table-bordered">
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <th> Sender </th>
        <td> Test </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th> Number </th>
        <td> 1234 </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

There is also a second table with no class nor id, which I would like to get separately. Is there a way to skip the first table?

```
<table class="table">
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <th> Table 2 cell 1 </th>
        <td> Test table 2 </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th> Number something </th>
        <td> 1234 table 2 </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

The output looks like this (json encoded):

```
[{"Sender":"Test"},{"Sender":"1234"},{"Sender":"Test table 2"},{"Sender":"1234 table 2"}]
```

Should be:

```
[{"Sender":"Test"},{"Number":"1234"},{"Table 2 cell 1":"Test table 2"},{"Number something":"1234 table 2"}]
```

Or ignoring the first table `table table-bordered`:

```
[{"Table 2 cell 1":"Test table 2"},{"Number something":"1234 table 2"}]
```

`Sender` should not be the key for each row. What should be changed in the PHP code to read this table correctly? I don't think the `$dom->find` is actually finding single rows and then looking for `th` and `td` inside.

Comment: Interestingly, `$rows = $dom->find('div.col-md-9');` solves the problem with incorrect array keys. This element contains both tables.

The array is now 
`[{"Sender":"Test"},{"Number":"1234"},{"Table 2 cell 1":"Test table 2"},{"Number something":"1234 table 2"}]` as needed.

I cannot explain why though. There are no tables outside of `div.col-md-9` and `$rows = $dom->find('div.col-md-9 table([class="table.table-bordered"]) tbody tr');` incorrectly returns the first key of `Sender` for all subsequent pairs.

Answer (score 0):

I think the following line of code will let you scrape the second table only. When you write like this `[class='table']` then the selector will ignore all the compound classes having the same portion within, meaning it will look for the class only having `table`.

Replace the following line with the existing one being used within your script:

```
$rows = $dom->find("[class='table'] tbody tr");
```

Comment: Unfortunately this still returns both. Also tried `$rows = $dom->find("table:not([class='table-bordered']) tbody tr");` to no avail.

Comment: That's really weird!! I tried my suggested selector on your above pasted html snippets using `.select()` in python and `.querySelector()` in vba and found the result as I told you. But unfortunately `simple_html_dom.php` working differently. However, I'm quite sure this is the way you should read that second table from that page without hardcoding index.

Comment: Yea, seems that `simple_html_dom.php` has some weird rules in the functions. I would have to go through a lot of code to figure it out. There are quite a few questions on stackexchange regarding ignoring elements with `:not` or `class!=foo`, but none work here.